# XML Cabeçalho Nota Fiscal Eletronica

Tags: xml, web-service, nfe

Estou com um problema de formatação da mensagem que enviamos ao web service do sefaz para consumirmos os serviço de NFe.

Envio essa String para o web service:

```
var sbXml = new StringBuilder();
            sbXml.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
             <consStatServ xmlns=""http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"" versao=""2.00"">
             <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
             <cUF>35</cUF>
             <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
             </consStatServ>");
```

Só que estou recebendo esta:

```
<retConsStatServ versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><tpAmb>2</tpAmb><verAplic>SP_NFE_PL_008f</verAplic><cStat>239</cStat><xMotivo>Rejeição: Cabeçalho - Versão do arquivo XML não suportada</xMotivo><cUF>35</cUF><dhRecbto>0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</dhRecbto></retConsStatServ>
```

Indicando o seguinte erro : **Versão do arquivo XML não suportada**

Alguém sabe que modificação tenho que fazer?, já verifiquei a versão esta certa, o Web Service aceita.

Comment: Você está dando escape nas aspas?
Você pode mostrar para nós o cabeçalho desse XML gerado por esse StringBuilder? 
Não aconselho que você crie XMLs assim.

Comment: Você está mandando pro service correto?

Comment: O resultado é esse:  
 
 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><consStatServ xmlns="portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"; versao="2.00"><tpAmb>2</tpAmb><cUF>35</cUF><xServ>STATUS</xServ></consStatServ>'

Comment: Qual o endereço do service que você está usando?

Comment: [https://homologacao.nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/nfestatusservico2.asmx]

Comment: Esse endereço é da versão 3. Veja aqui: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/WebServices.aspx. Tentou com `https://homologacao.nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/nfeweb/services/nfestatusservico2.asmx` ?

Comment: Cara por mais estranho que seja, eu já tinha feito um teste com 3.10 porém não funcionou, tentei novamente verificando o link no endereço da versão 3 e agora funcionou ¬.¬ !

Comment: Aliás, melhor já trabalhar com o 3.10 mesmo, logo acaba o prazo do 2.

Comment: Exato, vlw pela ajuda !